# How to determine if a pdf annotation will be visible or not in PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

I need to determine if an annotation will be visible or not in a PDF. I've checked options like: `isHidden=false`, `isNoView=false`, `isInvisible=false`. None of these seem to indicate that the annotation is hidden. But I have searched through the pdf after reading it using `pdfbox` and the annotation is indeed invisible. It does not show up in a text search or anywhere.

I've found the Annotation: `Archive Information` in `Adobe Acrobat Reader DC`. Looks to be a comment. How do I determine if this is the case? When I look at the `subtype` of the annotation it is `Text`.

(I'm not a pdf expert any help is appreciated).

[image]

Comment: If possible please share the pdf in question.

Comment: I can't is't a financial document ) :

Comment: I think the thing is the annotation is an instance of `PDAnnotationText` and some of these do not show up on the pdf.

Comment: Have you checked other properties? E.g. is the annotation rectangle too small to be visible? Or is it outside the page borders? And is it constructed correctly (incorrectly built annotations sometimes aren't displayed)? Have you checked whether there is a bug in your PDF viewer? ... There are very many possibilities why you don't see an annotation, so if you don't present more information, one can only guess.

Comment: `It does not show up in a text search or anywhere` - I don't know if annotations show up in Adobe text searches at all. The `Text` annotation is just a logo and a text that comes if the mouse hovers over it.

Comment: Allot of annotations do show up, but there are different types. Some are only visible when you open the pdf in certain readers/editors as they are comments only appearing on the right hand-side comments column such as with this one.

Comment: PDFBox can't tell how different readers will display the annotation. To me it is unclear what you want. Text annotations have a tiny logo, maybe you missed it. You can try to open the file with PDFDebugger and then search for that annotation in the tree by looking for the type and the content ("Archive Information").

Comment: Some annotations do show in all pdf readers, whilst some are comments, and you can only see them on a desktop reader. I don't know all the rules for the various cases and permutations of attributes and annotation types which is what I am asking. I don't know how to be more clear than that.

Answer (score 0):

In the end this is what did it for me, there are different types of `PDAnnotationText` which you can find in the class: `NAME_COMMENT, NAME_KEY, NAME_HELP`. The only one I actually want to detect being present is in-fact: `"Text"`.

```
if (annotation instanceof PDAnnotationText) {
    PDAnnotationText textAnnotation = (PDAnnotationText) annotation;
    String annotationName = textAnnotation.getName();
    if (annotationName != "Text") {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: The name is the name of the icon if there is no appearance stream. So maybe this works for you if all those PDFs are generated by the same software, but this isn't a general thing.